# What is the SQLAlchemy query to create an association from two tables in a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I've gotten in over my head and have been struggling to get this right for a day or so now in trying to create a simple web app.

I've created two classes seen below (User and RaidItem). My intent is to have an arbitrary amount of Users have "ownership" of a RaidItem. In doing my research I've discovered the need for an association table and have created the table as seen below.

```py
    association_table = db.Table('association',
                        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                        db.Column('raiditem_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('raid_item.id')))

    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
        items = db.relationship('RaidItem', secondary=association_table, backref = db.backref('owner'), lazy='dynamic')

    class RaidItem(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=False)
```

I've created a User and several RaidItems that have been populated within my database successfully.

In one of my routes I have a section to display "unowned items" and "owned items".

My current "unowned item" query looks like the below:

```py
items = RaidItem.query.filter(RaidItem.owners == None).all()
```

"Unowned Items" are displayed on the screen but my logic is wrong and I'm not sure how to solve it. Currently it shows all "unowned items" regardless of the user but I want to show only the "unowned items" for the individual user. To clarify, is user1 owns item1, user2 would not be able to see item1. That is not my intent.

My "owned items" query looks like the following:

```py
owned_items = RaidItem.query.join(association_table, (association_table.c.user_id == current_user.id)).filter(association_table.c.user_id == current_user.id)
```

If doesn't do what I intend, which is to only display the items that are currently "owned" by the current logged in user.

My question is two-fold:

> 1.) What is the SQLAlchemy query to create an association between the User and a created RaidItem **--and--**
>
> 2.) Once the associations have been created how do I query/filter based off of the "ownership" of the created item?

I've figured out in a comment below how to insert data manually into the association table but I'm still struggling to get these queries right.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: So I've been able to figure out how to insert information into the association table directly using the below statement: 

`db.session.execute(association_table.insert(), params={"user_id": 1, "raiditem_id": 1})`
I'm still struggling with getting the queries right. If anyone else has any insight let me know and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my problem by studying up on SQL queries and how to utilize db.engine.execute(). The code below is what I came up with in order to troubleshoot with raw SQL:

```py
owned_items = db.engine.execute(f'SELECT association.raiditem_id 
                                  FROM association 
                                  JOIN user 
                                  ON association.user_id = user.id 
                                  WHERE user.id = {current_user.id}')
```

The only issue was that this method didn't actually correctly reference the object stored in the database. I was able to use the SQLAlchemy query below to properly do so:

```py
owned_items = RaidItem.query.join(association_table).join(User).filter(association_table.c.user_id == current_user.id).all()
```

I hope this helps someone out in the future.